# Cleaning up large XML files in Python (stream parse)

Tags: python, xml

I tried to use Python to cleanup some messy XML files, which does three things:

1. Converting 40%-50% tag names from upper case to lower case
2. Removing NULL between tags
3. Removing empty rows between tags

I did this in using `BeautifulSoup`, however, I ran into memory issues since some of my XML files are over 1GB. Instead, I looked into some stream method like `xml.sax`, but I did not quite get the approach. So can anyone give me some suggestions?

```
xml_str = """
<DATA>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>1</assmtid>
        <Year>1988</Year>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>2</assmtid>
        <Year>NULL</Year>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>2</assmtid>
        <Year>1990</Year>
    </ROW>

</DATA>
"""

xml_str_update = re.sub(r">NULL", ">", xml_str)
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_str_update, "lxml")
print soup.data.prettify().encode('utf-8').strip()
```

### Update

After some testing and taking suggestions from Jarrod Roberson, below is one possible solution.

```
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

def getelements(xml_str):
    context = iter(etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml_str), events=('start', 'end')))
    event, root = next(context)

    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == "ROW":
            elem.tag = elem.tag.lower()
            elem.text = "\n\t\t"
            elem.tail = "\n\t"

            for child in elem:
                child.tag = child.tag.lower()
                if child.text == "NULL":
                    # if do not like self-closing tag, 
                    # add &#x200B;, which is a zero width space
                    child.text = ""  
                if child.text == None:
                    child.text = ""
                # print event, elem.tag
            yield elem
            root.clear()

with open(pth_to_output_xml, 'wb') as file:
    # start root
    file.write('<data>\n\t')
    for page in getelements(xml_str):
        file.write(etree.tostring(page, encoding='utf-8'))
    # close root
    file.write('</data>')
```

Comment: @alecxe- thanks for the suggestion. Does it require to explicitly list tags whose cases need to be converted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is lxml.etree.iterparse() eating up all my memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160418/why-is-lxml-etree-iterparse-eating-up-all-my-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Iterative parsing

> When building an in-memory tree is not desired or
> practical, use an iterative parsing technique that does not rely on
> reading the entire source file. lxml offers two approaches: Supplying
> a target parser class Using the iterparse method

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xmL, events=('start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns')):
  print event, elem
```

Here is a [very complete tutorial](http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html) on how to do this.

> This will parse the XML file in chunks at a time and give it to you at
> every step of the way. start will trigger when a tag is first
> encountered. At this point elem will be empty except for elem.attrib
> that contains the properties of the tag. end will trigger when the
> closing tag is encountered, and everything in-between has been read.

**Then in your event handlers you just write out the transformed information as it is encountered.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, in my case, I also need to output the whole XML file. Do you have any suggestions? Here is the latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715226/python-cleanup-large-xml-files-using-streaming-method

Comment: The very last line of my answer tells you what you need to be doing as does the answer in the duplicate.