# Python - Large XML to JSON to File / RAM and Swap Overload

Tags: python, xml, json, lxml, openstreetmap

I'm currently working on creating a Pythonic way of parsing through OpenStreetMaps province/states dumps; which as far as I know is just knowing how to deal with very large XML files (right?).

I'm currently using [lxml etree iterparse](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html) module in order to parse through the [dumps for the Province of Quebec](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/quebec.html)(quebec-latest.osm.bz2). I'd like to pull any entry that has highway information, convert to JSON, save it to file, and flush, though it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm currently running an i7-4770, 16GBs of RAM, 128GB SSD, and OSX 10.9. When I launch the code below, my RAM fills up completely within a couple seconds, and my swap within 30 seconds. Afterwards my system will either request that I close applications to make room, or eventually freeze.

Here's my code; You'll notice most likely a lot of bad/garbadge code in there, but I got to the point where I was plugging in whatever I could find in hope for it to work. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
import xmltodict, json, sys, os, gc

hwTypes = ['motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'pedestrian', 'unclassified', 'service']

#Enable Garbadge Collection
gc.enable()

def processXML(tagType):

    f = open('quebecHighways.json', 'w')
    f.write('[')
    print 'Processing '
    for event, element in etree.iterparse('quebec-latest.osm', tag=tagType):
        data = etree.tostring(element)
        data = xmltodict.parse(data)
        keys = data[tagType].keys()
        if 'tag' in keys:
            if isinstance(data[tagType]['tag'], dict):
                if data[tagType]['tag']['@k'] == 'highway':
                    if data[tagType]['tag']['@v'] in hwTypes:
                        f.write(json.dumps(data)+',')
                        f.flush() #Flush Python
                        os.fsync(f.fileno()) #Flush System
                        gc.collect() #Garbadge Collect
            else:
                for y in data[tagType]['tag']:
                    if y['@k'] == 'highway':
                        if y['@v'] in hwTypes:
                            f.write(json.dumps(data)+',')
                            f.flush()
                            os.fsync(f.fileno())
                            gc.collect()
                            break

        #Supposedly there is supposed to help clean my RAM.
        element.clear()
        while element.getprevious() is not None:
            del element.getparent()[0]

    f.write(']')
    f.close()
    return 0

processXML('way')
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7171543/407651.

Answer (score 0):

The library `xmltodict` stores the dictionary generated in memory, so if your data dictionaries are big it is not really a good idea to do so. Using only `iterparse` would be more efficient.

Another option could be to use the streaming possibilities offered by xmltodict. More info in http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/xmltodict.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are making your life more complicated than necessary. You are effectively repeatedly dumping whole subtree into `xmltodict` and making it parse that whole subtree again and again.

If I were you, I would just dump `xmltodict`, sit on your behind, read a tutorial or two, and just use something standard: `xml.sax` (it is really not that difficult, if you don't need too many jumps ahead; just working on [converting Bible](https://gitlab.com/bible_sword/CzeKMS/blob/XSLT2SAX/CEPtoOSIS.py)) or `iterparse` and use just that. It is really not that complicated.