# Parse/read Large XML file with minimal memory footprint

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing

I have a very large XML file (300mb) of the following format:

```
<data>
 <point>
  <id><![CDATA[1371308]]></id>
  <time><![CDATA[15:36]]></time>
 </point>
 <point>
  <id><![CDATA[1371308]]></id>
  <time><![CDATA[15:36]]></time>
 </point>
 <point>
  <id><![CDATA[1371308]]></id>
  <time><![CDATA[15:36]]></time>
 </point>
</data>
```

Now I need to read it and iterate through the `point` nodes doing something for each. Currently I'm doing it with Nokogiri like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xmlfeed = Nokogiri::XML(open("large_file.xml"))
xmlfeed.xpath("./data/point").each do |item|
  save_id(item.xpath("./id").text)
end
```

However that's not very efficient, since it parses everything whole hug, and hence creating a huge memory footprint (several GB).

Is there a way to do this in chunks instead? Might be called streaming if I'm not mistaken?

**EDIT**

The suggested answer using nokogiris sax parser might be okay, but it gets very messy when there is several nodes within each `point` that I need to extract content from and process differently. Instead of returning a huge array of entries for later processing, I would much rather prefer if I could access one `point` at a time, process it, and then move on to the next "forgetting" the previous.

Comment: +1 for presenting it in well manner..

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allow you to search through large xml using ox, allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this little-known (but AWESOME) [gist](https://gist.github.com/kmile/827475) using Nokogiri's Reader interface, you should be able to do this:

```
Xml::Parser.new(Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(file))) do
  inside_element 'point' do
    for_element 'id' do puts "ID: #{inner_xml}" end
    for_element 'time' do puts "Time: #{inner_xml}" end
  end
end
```

Someone should make this a gem, perhaps me ;)

Comment: Very interesting! Could be cool with a gem inspired by https://github.com/pauldix/sax-machine but with the large file parsing scope

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Parser.html) (event-driven parser) and [`Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Document.html):

```
require 'nokogiri'

class IDCollector < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  attr :ids

  def initialize
    @ids = []
    @inside_id = false
  end

  def start_element(name, attrs)
    # NOTE: This is simplified. You need some kind of stack manipulations
    #                           (push in start_element / pop in end_element)
    #    to correctly pick `.//data/point/id` elements.
    @inside_id = true if name == 'id'
  end
  def end_element(name)
    @inside_id = false
  end

  def cdata_block string
    @ids << string if @inside_id
  end
end

collector = IDCollector.new
parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(collector)
parser.parse(File.open('large_file.xml'))
p collector.ids # => ["1371308", "1371308", "1371308"]
```

According to [the documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Parser.html),

> `Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser`: is a SAX style parser that reads its
>   input as it deems necessary.

You can also use [`Nokogiri::XML::SAX::PushParser`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/PushParser.html) if you need more control over the file input.

Comment: Hmm okay, that's one way - but is it really the simplest? I would have expected something a little less "complicated"...

Comment: @NielsKristian, I don't know simpler way. I wish other guys come up with better solutions.

Comment: @NielsKristian, `end_element` could be dropped, if you replace `start_element` definition as `def start_element(name, attrs); @inside_id = name == 'id' end`.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm wondering if there is any nice gems out there that would wrap this kind of functionality up in a more convenient DSL

Comment: @NielsKristian, If you don't mind to use Python, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171140/using-python-iterparse-for-large-xml-files) that use lxml.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jruby, you can take advantage of vtd-xml, which has the most efficient in memory model, 3~5x more efficient than DOM..

http://vtd-xml.sf.net