# Python XML iterparse() namespacing

Tags: python, xml, lxml, iterparse

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171140/using-python-iterparse-for-large-xml-files?answertab=active#tab-top), I successfully can parse my XML file, and reading it's content. However, if I add namespace to it, the whole thing goes wrong.

Let's consider the following XML:

```
<root xmlns="MyNamespace">
   <A1>
     <B1></B1>
     <C>1<D1></D1></C>
     <E1></E1>
   </A1>
   <A2>
      <B2></B2>
       <C>2<D></D></C>
       <E2></E2>
   </A2>
</root>
```

My iterparse looks like this:

```
context = ET.iterparse('../in/process/teszt.xml', events=('end', ), tag='B1')
```

I found several examples, but to be honest I don't really understand them, and have no idead how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of XML with *default namespace*, you need to use the namespace URI along with the element's local name in `tag` :

```
context = ET.iterparse('../in/process/teszt.xml', events=('end', ), tag='{MyNamespace}B1')
```