# Parsing XML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Edit: resolved. Thought I'd add my answer at the bottom...

Note: the desired output is a bunch of lines like

```
US D0591026
```

I have data that looks like the following in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23" file="USD0591026-20090428.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20090414" date-publ="20090428">
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
<publication-reference>
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>D0591026</doc-number>
<kind>S1</kind>
<date>20090428</date>
</document-id>
</publication-reference>
<application-reference appl-type="design">
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>29303426</doc-number>
<date>20080208</date>
</document-id>
</application-reference>
<us-application-series-code>29</us-application-series-code>
<priority-claims>
<priority-claim sequence="01" kind="national">
<country>CA</country>
<doc-number>122078</doc-number>
<date>20070830</date>
</priority-claim>
</priority-claims>
<us-term-of-grant>
<length-of-grant>14</length-of-grant>
</us-term-of-grant>
<classification-locarno>
<edition>9</edition>
<main-classification>0101</main-classification>
</classification-locarno>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 1106</main-classification>
</classification-national>
<invention-title id="d0e71">Edible fruit product in the shape of a rocketship</invention-title>
<references-cited>
```

I am trying to pull out the country, and the document number. I've gotten to this point:

```
import os
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

directory_in_str = 'C:/Users/somedirectory'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    full_name = directory_in_str + filename
    handler = open(full_name).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')
    patents=soup.find_all('us-patent-grant')
    pub_ref=soup.find_all('publication-reference')
    country=soup.find_all('country')
    doc_num=soup.find_all('doc-number')
    for patent in pub_ref:
        for doc_num in patent:
            print(doc_num)

    continue
```

Where I can print out a nice block that includes those elements (what the code above does), but everything I have tried to get at those two specific elements (and then concatenate them) has failed. I've been able to do it with string operations, but the dataset isn't well formatted enough (I will be pulling out textfields without a standard length later) to feel confident that I can perform the whole analysis based on splicing strings.

Any ideas how I can drill down into those further tags and return just those two elements?

Ok, so I have made some changes, and gotten my code to:

```
import os
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

directory_in_str = 'C:/somedir'

directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    full_name = directory_in_str + filename
    handler = open(full_name).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')
    patents=soup.find_all('us-patent-grant')
    pub_ref=soup.find_all('publication-reference')
    for patent in pub_ref:
     country = patent.find_all('country')
     doc_num = patent.find_all('doc-number')
     print(country + doc_num)

    continue
```

Which gives me *most* of what I want. I am getting this:

```
[<country>US</country>, <doc-number>D0591026</doc-number>]
```

but what I want is just:

```
US D0591026
```

I understand the type of the object is a bs4 result set, but I am not familiar enough with how I only return the things in the tag. Eventually, this is going to a csv, so I don't want to have those tags in there.

I converted the soup objects to strings and used regular expressions to get the desired output

```
...
import re
...
...
     country = patent.find_all('country')
     doc_num = patent.find_all('doc-number')
     country_str = str(country)
     doc_num_str = str(doc_num)
     country_str2 = re.search('>(.*)<', country_str)
     doc_num_str2 = re.search('>(.*)<', doc_num_str)
     print(country_str2.group(1) + doc_num_str2.group(1))
```

Comment: Have you looked into XPath or using the `etree` module instead? Beautfulsoup is primarily for HTML, in my experience

Comment: I don't understand your desired output, is it one list which elements are a lists with the doc-number and it's related country?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your desired Output.

Comment: Thanks, cricket_007, I tried etree, but all I get is this error: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &copy;: line 56, column 106. If I understand the documentation for etree right, that means the xml is non-standard, so I'd have to add each non-conforming element/tag?

Comment: There is no `&copy;` entity reference in the XML document that you have shown us. It is also not well-formed; end tags are missing.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think your solution using `re` is overkill, you can select the text inside a tag in bs4 simply using `.text`, as suggested by me and gipsy in our answers. I'm glad you got your issue solved, but editing the question to include your answer is against the SO guidelines, you should rather post your answer as an answer to your own question, and then [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the most helpful answer, it's an overall good for the community.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list with `doc-number` and it's related `country` using list comprehension and `zip`, a simple one-liner would be:

```
>>> [(country.text,number.text) for country, number in zip(soup.findAll("country"), soup.findAll("doc-number"))]
[('US', 'D0591026'), ('US', '29303426'), ('CA', '122078')]
```

Or perhaps a more readable way if you are not used to list comprehensions:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> for country, number in zip(soup.findAll("country"), soup.findAll("doc-number")):
    print(country.text, number.text)
    lst.append((country.text, number.text))


US D0591026
US 29303426
CA 122078
>>> lst
[('US', 'D0591026'), ('US', '29303426'), ('CA', '122078')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
doc_nums=soup.find_all('doc-number')
for num in doc_nums:
  print(num.text)
```