# fast checking the existence of tag in large XML using python cElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

I have XML files with sizes of hundreds of megabytes to tens of gigabytes and use `Python's` `cElementTree` to process them. Due to limited memory and low speed, I don't want to load all contents into memory using `et.parse` then `find` or `findall` method to find whether the tag exists (I didn't try this way, actually). Now I simply use `et.iterparse` to iterate through all tags to achieve this aim. In the case that the tag locates close to the end of the file, this can be very slow as well. I wonder whether there exists a better way to achieve this and get the location of the tag? If I know the top level (e.g., index) the tag locates, at which the size is much smaller than other parts of the file, is it possible to iterate through the top level tag and then target that part to parse? I searched online, but surprisingly no related questions are posted. Do I miss anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python Iterparse For Large XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171140/using-python-iterparse-for-large-xml-files)

Comment: @stovfl No! I said I have already used `iterparse` to go through all tags to avoid memory problem, the same as what have been posted there. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: ***" to avoid memory problem"***: The accepted answer, show how to avoid ***memory problem***.

Comment: @stovfl This problem has already been solved by using `clear` method. I mean it's still very slow to iterate through all tags using `iterparse` to find out whether the tag exists. My question is can I achieve this in a much faster way? This is what I asked for, not memory problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reading the file block by block instead of parsing the file using `cElementTree`. My tags are close to the end of the file, so according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646049/3003072), I read a block of contexts with specified size `block_size` at a time from the end of the file by using `file.seek` and `file.read` methods, and `line = f.read(block_size)`, and then simply using `"<my_tag " in line` (or more specific tag name to avoid ambiguity) to check whether the tag exists. This is much faster then using `iterparse` to go through all tags.