# how to iterate on xml nodes (both elements and text nodes) in python2 etree

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a xml, in where an element contains multiple text nodes. Using python2 `etree`, I want to navigate the tree with the same order.

So, for this input:

```
<body>
  hello
  <b>world</b>
  bye
</body>
```

I need to be able to produce this output in **this exact order**:

```
tag: body
   text: hello
   tag: b
       text: world
   text: bye
```

However, I do not see in `etree` a function to iterate on both elements and text nodes.

How can I do that?
I am looking for something such as (the function `iterateElementsAndTextNodes` does not exists):

```
from lxml import etree
import utils

doc = etree.XML("""<body>hello<b>world</b>bye</body>""")

def printNode(node, prefix):
    if isinstance(node, str):
        print prefix + "text: " + node
    else:
        print prefix + "tag:" + node.tag
        for c in node.iterateElementsAndTextNodes():
            printNode(c, prefix + "   ")

printNode(doc, "")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to iterate throught xml elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695826/efficient-way-to-iterate-throught-xml-elements)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `child::node()` in xpath to select all the children of the context node, whatever their node type. [Read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5119937/3083243)
So, changing the for loop to:

```
for c in node.xpath("child::node()"):
    printNode(c, prefix + "   ")
```

Code:

```
from lxml import etree
import utils

doc = etree.XML("""<body>hello<b>world</b>bye</body>""")
#print "doc is", etree.tostring(doc)
def printNode(node, prefix):
    if isinstance(node, etree._ElementStringResult):
        print prefix + "text: " + node
    else:
        print prefix + "tag: " + node.tag
        for c in node.xpath("child::node()"):
            printNode(c, prefix + "   ")
printNode(doc, "")
```